# Redirecting USB scanner to windows machine

Tags: windows, usb

We have a Linux thin client that connects to the Windows terminal server via RDP. We need to redirect USB scanner that plugged to the Linux machine to the Windows terminal server.

What is most appropriate free (as in free beer is enough) solution? I have tried to use freerdp USB redirection, but it didn't work. Maybe I  had done something wrong. If anybody has positive experience with freerdp, I will try once more.

I plan to try USB-IP project, but it seems neglected, especially Windows client.

Comment: Does SANE have a driver for your scanner? (If you don't know, please give scanner make/model # and USB IDs and hopefully someone else knows). There are apparently both TWANE and WIA drivers for SANE.

Comment: I don't know because we plan to use this solution for clients of our company.  Therefore it may be any model of scanner (maybe bought a long time ago and without taking into account Linux support), and it shall work even if it is not supported in Linux.

It will work via USB-IP, but I'm afraid that it's unstable. There are proprietary analogs, as example Eltima USB Network Gate, but they are requiring payment.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from 2019: There seem to be a few implementations of [usbip](/questions/tagged/usbip) V2 clients available online, [opensource@github](https://github.com/barbalion/usbip-win-client) is one of them. [here is another](https://github.com/cezuni/usbip-win).

There seems to be cross-platform compatibility with at least Linux, Windows, Openwrt and Android. Probably Mac too.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualHere](https://www.virtualhere.com/) seems to be what you are looking for. Free for only one device.

> "VirtualHere allows USB devices to be used remotely over a network just
>   as if they were locally connected"